# How to close navigation drawer when an item is pressed from it?

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

Ideally navigation drawer should get closed once some item has been pressed from it, but its not happening automatically. How to do it ?
Thanks!

Comment: Which libary do you use to get the navigation drawer?

Answer (score 253, accepted):

Got it!

```
private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();
```

Working perfectly fine.

Comment: Can it be closed without animation?

Comment: Hamzeh - mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(Gravity.LEFT, false); would result in closing it without animation

Comment: mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START, false);

Answer (score 13):

For me this one worked -

```
mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(Gravity.START, false);
```

Answer (score 9):

```
DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout= (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout)

closeDrawer(); // called when you want to close

public void closeDrawer() {
  if (mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
    mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

```
closeDrawer();//when you want to call

public void closeDrawer() {
    if (mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

If you have mDrawerLayout as your drawer layout, you can close it when it is open.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (this.mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        this.mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

On the right bottom of onNavigationItemSelected where the switch case ends you should right this. mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();

```
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()){

        }
   mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();
   return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This work,kotlin code

```
drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, but it's a duplicate of multiple other answer such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56766056/10952503)