# how to close navigation drawer on item click

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, navigation-drawer

I'm trying to close naviagtion drawer on my project with this code:

```
   override fun onNavigationItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
        drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START)

        return true
    }
```

I have done done some research but it hasn't helped so far, I even tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48897678)..

But for some reason it's not closing, please what might be wrong??

Answer (score 1):

I didn't add:

```
navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this)
```

to the `onCreate` function.. I've added it, and it works fine..

Here's what it looks like;

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    setSupportActionBar(toolbar)
    val toggle = ActionBarDrawerToggle(this ,drawerLayout, toolbar, R.string.open, R.string.close)
    toggle.isDrawerIndicatorEnabled = true
    drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(toggle)
    toggle.syncState()

    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this)
}

override fun onNavigationItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
    drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START)

    return true
}
```